# Contact picker that shows number, contact name and possibly a contact image?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, android-contacts

Is there any way to display contact picker that has both number and contact name?

Now I'm calling picker:

```
startActivityForResult(
                       new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI),
                       1);
```

But in a result I get only Contact names without visible numbers. To make things worse, if one contact has two numbers it occurs twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this. its just like the contact picker, but lists clickable phone numbers under the contacts name

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can check out the free Android contact picker library at https://github.com/codinguser/android_contact_picker
which allows a user to

- pick a contact from a list of contacts,
- display the details and
- then select a number (and then you can do what you want with the number)

*Disclosure: I am the author of this library*

Comment: @СвятославЗайцев The library has been upgraded to aar packaging in version 3.0.0 which is supported by gradle.
It is also now possible to search contacts and create a new contact amongst other enhancements.

Comment: i am getting erro       java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.codinguser.android.contactpicker.R$id.action_search
                                                       at com.codinguser.android.contactpicker.ContactsListFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(ContactsListFragment.java:109) how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and could not find any way to display the required information together.

Finally I created a ListView and display the Contact along with the Number information. You can refer to this tutorial to build one easily - http://www.droidnova.com/first-list-application,37.html