# Displaying contacts only with phone numbers using ACTION_PICK intent in Android device

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

My goal is to only display contacts with phone number to user and let user select few contacts which I want to store locally.

I have used various options in place of ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI in below method. But I am getting lot many of the contacts (many are junk with only email ids) displayed.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.contact_selector);

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnphonecontactlist)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Intent contactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(contactIntent, 1);
              }
           });
    }
```

If I pass ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI as parameter for above method and in case of below handler method,  the String[] for the query method as projection parameters (which are shown commented), the method fails with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. If I pass null in below method, then whatever contact I select, I don't find any column related to phone number or email.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(data != null)
        {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if(uri != null)
            {
                Cursor c = null;

                try
                {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null
                                                // new String[] { 
                            //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, 
                            //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE}, 
                            , null, null, null);

                    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        String type = c.getString(1);
                    }               
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(c != null && !c.isClosed())
                        c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to display only contacts visible to user usually when user goes to phone book and which has phone numbers available?

I tried going through all the threads in stackoverflow and other sites, but could not find any solution which resolve issue around this though many people have posted the issue. I haven't worked much with the Android platform and I might have missed out certain minor details and I believe there must be an easy way to achieve this.

Kindly suggest. Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please use below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I just jumped to coding without reading much of the basics. I used ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE but now I see there are such other options and the difference between them.

Comment: Though I did not see email info returned for the contact. Isn't there any string parameter which can bring all the contact related info, including home, mobile numbers and emails?

Comment: After going through more details and reading at below post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612531/how-can-i-choose-a-phone-number-with-androids-contacts-dialog it becomes very clear on what to be required to get the email and phone number both. To put it in short, after retrieving _id for the selected contact, from the intent displayed from above example, we need to re-query using contact resolver, passing the _id and appropriate Uri for Phone number and email to retrieve required details. Also link explains about how to handle scenario if the given contact has multiple phone numbers.

Comment: Like this is what type we use  to get contacts who have mailid's?

Comment: didn't understand your question

Answer (score 3):

```
*-> Add a permission to read contacts data to your application manifest.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

-> Use Intent.ACTION_PICK in your Activity 

Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);

-> Then Override the onActivityResult() and retrieve the ID,Phone number and Name in the data. 

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // check whether the result is ok
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple startActivityForReslut
            switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:
               Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String phoneNo = null ;
            String name = null;           
            Uri uri = data.getData();            
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();           
            int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex); 

            textView2.setText(phoneNo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                break;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to pick contact");
        }
    }

This will work check it out*
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will do what you want.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Contact"), PICK_CONTACT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://contacts");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
intent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people"));
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```