# Contact chooser returning null value

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to implement contact pciker in android, i am able to launch contact picker in android, but when i select the contact i get back null value, i.e. no number in my textfield. What am i doing wrong ?

Here is my code.

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.textmessage;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
     protected static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 0;


    int count=0;


     private RadioButton radioBtnten;
      private RadioButton radioBtnone;

   Button sendBtn,contact;
   EditText txtphoneNo;
   EditText txtMessage;
   GPSTracker gps;
   Timer timer;

    TimerTask timerTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
      boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
      if (!enabled) 
      {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your GPS IS NOT ON SWITCH IT ON HERE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
      } 
      radioBtnten=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ten);
      radioBtnone=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.one);
      sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
      txtphoneNo= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
     contact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.contact);
      //txtMessage //= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);
      gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

      contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
              intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
              startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

          }
       });
   }
      @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          Uri contact = data.getData();
          ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = managedQuery(contact, null, null, null, null);
        //      c.moveToFirst();


        while(c.moveToNext()){
            String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                while(pCur.moveToNext()){
                    String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                    txtphoneNo.setText(phone);
                }
            }
      }
      sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             startTimer();
            sendSMSMessage();
            Intent toAnotherActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, maps.class);
            startActivityForResult(toAnotherActivity, 0);

         }
      });
   }


   public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, after the first 5000ms the TimerTask will run every 10000ms//
         if(radioBtnten.isChecked()==true)
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 10000);
        // if(radioBtn2.isSelected()==true)
         else if(radioBtnone.isChecked()==true)
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 1000);
    }
   public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //get the current timeStamp


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your message has been sent, the message(s) sent are:-"+count++,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        sendSMSMessage();

                        //show the toast


                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

   public void stoptimertask(View v) 
   {
        //stop the timer, if it's not already null

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop button pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (timer != null) 
        {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
   protected void sendSMSMessage() {
      Log.i("Send SMS", "");
    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

      String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
      String message = "These are my co-ordinates:-"+ latitude + ", " + longitude; 

      try {
         SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
         smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "SMS faild, please try again.",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
}
```

P.S. i have mentioned the permission in manifest.

Comment: See following post [How can I choose a phone number with Android's contacts dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612531/how-can-i-choose-a-phone-number-with-androids-contacts-dialog) probably help

Comment: sorry prosper, it was of little help

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems to be you have not added onActivityResult method. Put the following code in in onActivityResult method

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data); 

    Uri contact = data.getData();
     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
    Cursor c = managedQuery(contact, null, null, null, null); 
     while(c.moveToNext()){
     String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
     String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
    if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
     Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
     while(pCur.moveToNext()){ 
    String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
     tv.setText( phone);
     }
 }
 }}
```

Comment: where should i put thtat code ? i have tried that code before, it does not fit my expectations

Comment: In your inactivityresult method

Comment: i do nt have inactivityresult  method

Comment: Create one in your activity as mentioned in the answer

Comment: where is it mentioned in answer ? :-)

Comment: public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data); 
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71429/discussion-between-penta-and-fahim).